# How to correctly add the ZendFramework to the php.ini file?

Tags: php, zend-framework

The ZendFramework is uploaded in `C:\phpincludes\ZendFramework`

I added the ZendFramework library to the php.ini file:

```
Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path = ".;c:\phpincludes\ZendFramework\library"
```

and then I am calling these functions at the top of my index.php:

```
<?php
require_once('Zend/Mail.php'); 
require_once('Transport/Smtp.php'); 
?>
```

I get an error saying `require_once(Zend/Mail.php)`: failed to open stream.

Comment: Are you sure it is `phpincludes` & not `php\includes` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also check if ".;c:\phpincludes\ZendFramework\library" directory has correct access permission.

Answer (score 1):

Your include path appears to be correct. Are your sure you have edited the correct **php.ini** file and have your restarted your webserver / apache service (otherwise the changes aren't applied)?

You can check your include path in PHP to make sure it is loaded correctly using:

```
echo get_include_path();
```

Comment: also check your php.ini for other include_path entries. some server installs (Zend Server for example) will put an include_Path entry down at the bottom of the file that will override the normal entry.